# How to count the cell value having time that how many are less than or greater than 12:00pm

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a production schedule on MS EXCEL and I need to count how many batches were produced in the day shift and how many were produced in night shift. Whenever task is completed the time is mentioned. I need to count that how many cells have time which is less than 03:00pm and how many cells have time greater than 03:00pm.

To simplify, there are 3 columns: "tasks", "date" and "time". When the operator enters "complete" in "tasks" column automatically the date and and time are updated which is by using IF() and Today() functions. This data is for each day of the week. I need to count how many tasks were completed on say 06-06-2018 in the day shift (before 03:00pm) and how many were completed in night/evening shift (after 03:00pm).

Hope I am clear enough for everyone to understand.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
'for 06-Jun-2018 12:00 am to 06-Jun-2018 03:00 pm
=countifs([datetime_column], ">="&date(2018, 6, 6), [datetime_column], "<"&date(2018, 6, 6)+time(15, 0, 0))
'for 06-Jun-2018 03:00 pm to 07-Jun-2018 12:00 am
=countifs([datetime_column], "<"&date(2018, 6, 7), [datetime_column], ">="&date(2018, 6, 6)+time(15, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Before 3:00 PM

```
=COUNTIFS([datetime_column],">="&[date_cell],[datetime_column],"<"&[date_cell]+TIME(15, 0, 0))
```

After 3:00 PM

```
=COUNTIFS([datetime_column],"<="&[date_cell]+1,[datetime_column], ">"&[date_cell]+TIME(15, 0, 0))
```

But remember if you used IF(), Today(), and NOW() functions date and time will be updated to the current date each time calculation is done.

EXAMPLE

[Your inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N00wI.png)

[The output_FORMULA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7tl8.png)

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgEab.png)

Answer (score 0):

It guess may be the time.
Before 03:00pm time

```
=COUNTIFS([datetime_column],">="&[date_cell],[datetime_column],"<"&[date_cell]+TIME(15, 0, 0))
```

After 03:00pm time

```
=COUNTIFS([datetime_column],"<="&[date_cell],[datetime_column],">"&[date_cell]+TIME(15, 0, 0))
```

That's it, 03:00pm is actually the same as 15:00
You can also be!
Before 15:00 time

```
=COUNTIFS([datetime_column],">="&[date_cell],[datetime_column],"<"&[date_cell]+TIME(15, 0, 0))
```

After 15:00 time

```
=COUNTIFS([datetime_column],"<="&[date_cell],[datetime_column],">"&[date_cell]+TIME(15, 0, 0))
```